# How do I use ember-cli with the LTS release channel?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I would like to update an addon to the long term support release channel using ember-cli. How do I do this?

I know I can put a different version of ember and ember-data in de bower.json and package.json files. But will updates of ember-cli not interfere with these older versions?

Also what is the lts release of ember-data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current LTS is 2.4, so you need to open your `bower.json` and in the ember line, put the following:

```
"ember": "~2.4.0"
```

This should install the latest 2.4 at the time of the install.

> But will updates of ember-cli not interfere with these older versions?

Ember CLI is mostly decoupled from Ember itself, so it can be used with almost any version. When ember.js is converted into an addon (like what happened with ember-data), you'll need to mind the update instructions for it, so you continue to use the bower package instead of the npm addon.

At the moment Ember Data does not have an LTS.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I'm aware of this. But I wonder if ember-cli updates would not break this and also if ember-data has a lts release. I'll update my question.

Comment: Edited, hope the added info is useful.